# How do I change the accent color in Android's Material theme alerts?

Tags: android, android-theme, material-design

I have the following theme declaration in my values-v21 folder:

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/brand_primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar_bg</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#FF00FF</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">#0000FF</item>
</style>
```

These colors apply to everything as expected (e.g. status bar or action mode) but all the controls (check boxes, radios, and buttons) in alerts still have the default turquoise color. Is there a way to colorize them too?

p.s. I'm not using the appcompat library, for the purpose of this question you should pretend I don't support anything below Lollipop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume by "alert" you mean a `Dialog`. These are controlled by a different theme reference:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/BaseDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="BaseDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">...</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It worked but with colorAccent instead of colorPrimary.